# transformation of a ball to an other by homothety

Tags: general-topology, affine-geometry

While reading a proof in which they have defined the following homothety 
$$\begin{align*}
  h \colon C &\to C\\
  x &\mapsto a+t(x-a)
\end{align*}$$
where $a\in C$, C is a convex set of a normed space E and $t\in [0,1]$;

I didn't understand why they said that this homothety transform the ball $B(b,r)$ to $B(a+t(b-a),rt)$,  where $b\in int(C)$. I tried to show that but in vain, any hint will be very helpful. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The map $h$ is a composition of three simpler maps.

The first map is a translation which shifts $a$ to the origin.

The second map is dilation by a factor of $t$.

The third map is a translation which shifts the origin back to $a$.

Now, determine what each of these simple maps does to the ball $B(b,r)$ as you apply the maps one by one.

**Addendum:** You may find the following useful. For $t\in (0,1]$,
$$||x-b||<r \iff ||t(x-b)||<rt$$
and
$$t(x-b)=a+t(x-a) -[a+t(b-a)] =h(x)-[a+t(b-a)]
$$

Comment: using your hint I can just see what's happening to the origin of the ball but what about the ray ?

Comment: A translation maps circles to circles. A dilation with factor $t$ maps a circle of radius $r$ centered at the base point to a circle of radius $tr$ with the same center.

Comment: yes I see what you mean it's intuitive, but I was wondering if you have a reference cause I really want to see how to demonstrate that using topological stuffs like the norm the continuity of $h$... if it's possible of course. thank you for your help

Comment: I added an addendum that may help

Comment: yes it did really help thank you, the last equality wasn't correct so I edited it.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. I trimmed down what I was going to post originally and made an error in the process, sorry. I think I've corrected it now. Thanks for that, should be ok now.